# ImportError: No module named 'celery' in proj/proj/celery.py

Tags: python, django, celery

I have been following the tutorial in
[Celery: First steps with django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

proj/proj/celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

proj/proj/*init*.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

sampleapp/tasks.py:

```
# Create your tasks here
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@shared_task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y


@shared_task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

I'm pretty sure I correctly followed it however i got an error message when I start running `python3 manage.py runserver`

This is the error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/main/actinbox/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "/app/main/actinbox/celery.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: No module named 'celery'
```

I have already installed celery and as well as rabbitmq-server.

Do you guys have any idea what happened?
Did I miss something?

the version of my celery is 4.0.0
django 1.10.2
python 3.5.2

Comment: Do you have `celery` installed? If not, do `sudo pip3 install celery`  (`pip3` instead of `pip` as you are using python3)

Comment: oh thanks.. I will try

Comment: Don't use name `celery.py` for your files because now `import` loads your file instead expected library.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see in logs - you named a file in your project `celery.py` so basically python tries to find the Celery there - try to rename things :)

Comment: This is a great advice... Thank you so much